Conditional expectation as a projection
I don't understand how conditional expectation is a projection.
I have a probably space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{R})$, and a random variable $X: \Omega $ to $\mathbb{R}$ then conditionnal expectation is defined as:
$$E[X | \sigma(K)] = p_{L^2(\Omega, \sigma(K), \mathbb{P})}(X)$$
So the condional expectation is defined as the projection of $X$ on the new space: $L^2(\Omega, \sigma(K), \mathbb{P})$.
Now I was trying to understand what this projection on this new space means. For $\omega \in \Omega$ we can defined all the indicators functions $1_{\omega}$ which form a basis of $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{R})$.
We can write:
$$X= \sum a_\omega \cdot 1_{\omega}$$ where the $a_w \in \mathbb{R}$.
But then since the basis of the space $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{R})$ is defined in terms of $\Omega$ and not $\mathcal{F}$ then the basis of the spaces: $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{R})$ and $L^2(\Omega, \sigma(K), \mathbb{P})$ are the same. (I guess the sigma field only restrict the $a_{\omega}$ we can use in the linear combination).
So how can I understand projection in this setting. I always understandood projection on a subspace, as the projection on the basis of that subspace, but here I don't see how it works? I feel like changing the sigma field doesn't change the basis of the space but more the avilable linear combination we can make of the basis vectors...

Your definition isn't written precisely. I'll write it out in full detail. We work on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Suppose $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Note that $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P)$ is a closed linear subspace of the Hilbert space $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Hence given $X \in L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, we can define
$$E(X \mid \mathcal{G}) = P_{L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P)}X = \text{argmin}_{Y \in L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P)}E(|X - Y|^2).$$
In other words, $E(X \mid \mathcal{G})$ is the orthogonal projection of $X$ onto $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P)$. This is a Hilbert space projection, so if you have an orthonormal basis $e_1, e_2, \dots$ of $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P)$, then
$$E(X \mid \mathcal{G}) = \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}E(X e_j)e_j.$$
This formula is only useful in special cases when you have the basis, as in elementary conditional probability.

Thank you for your answer. But then do you agree that the $1_{\omega}$ aform a basis of the space: $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P)$ but also of the space $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$? I don't get how the sigma field change the basis of the space? For me projection is a reduction of dimension not a reduction of measure

Do you understand what the space $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P)$ is and how it is smaller than $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$? No, $1_{\omega}$ do not form a basis of $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ unless $\Omega$ is countable. Consult section 4.1 of https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf for examples

Yes I understand what these spaces represent. I am just used to think of projections in term of expressing a vector in term of basis that I project on an other space span by an other basis. But I don't see what type of functions are the basis of $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P)$ and $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. For example I would expect the $1_{\omega}$ to be a basis of $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ but maybe when it's not countable there are some weird things happening...

Basically I want to understand, how changing the sigma field affect the basis of the space

Think of projection is finding the closest point. The basis view is only a formula, but the important point is that the projection is the nearest point in the subspace. Changing the sigma-field changes which functions are measurable, and therefore changes the basis. You should work out the case where $\mathcal{G}$ is the sigma algebra generated by finitely many sets $A_1, \dots, A_n$. You'll see exactly what you want to know about.

@missing_name: This may provide some of the intuition you are looking for. It's an elaboration of what Kakashi said in his comment immediately above. https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/pitman/s205f02/lecture15.pdf
