Sum of subspaces in L^2 defined by sigma algebras
At moment I am reading "Foundations of Modern Probability" by Olav Kallenberg and am having problems understanding a particular characterisation of conditional independence as a property of $L^2$ projections (Theorem 8.13, first equivalence):
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a measure space with corresponding $L^2$ space. Furthermore, let $\mathcal{F}$, $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ be sigma algebras and $F, G, H \subseteq L^2$ be those subspaces of $L^2$ containing only $\mathcal{F}$ or $\mathcal{G}$ or $\mathcal{H}$ measurable random variables with mean zero, respectively. So for example:
$$
F = \{ X \in L^2 \, : \, X \text{ is } \mathcal{F} \text{ measurable and } \mathbb{E}[X] = 0\}
$$
Now define $F + G$ as the closure of span($F,G$) and $\pi_F, \pi_G, \pi_{F + G}$ as the respective orthogonal projections.
Theorem:
If $\pi_{F+G} (H) = \pi_{G}(H)$ then $F$ and $H$ are independent given $G$, i.e. $F \perp H \, | \, G$.
Why does this hold?
I tried solving this but got stuck at showing that $\chi_{A\cap B} \in F + G$ if $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $B \in \mathcal{G}$ with indicator function $\chi$.

Let $A\in \mathcal F$ and $B\in\mathcal H$, then:
\begin{gather*}
P(A\cap B\mid\mathcal G)=\\
=E[1_A.1_B\mid\mathcal G]=E\big[E[1_A.1_B\mid\mathcal F,\mathcal G]\mid\mathcal G\big]=E\big[1_A.E[1_B\mid\mathcal F,\mathcal G]\mid\mathcal G\big]=\\
=E\big[1_A.E[1_B\mid\mathcal G]\mid\mathcal G\big]=E[1_A\mid\mathcal G].E[1_B\mid\mathcal G]=\\
=P(A\mid\mathcal G).P(B\mid\mathcal G)
\end{gather*}

Thank you for your answer! This uses the property $E[X | \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}] = E[X | \mathcal{G}]$ if $X$ is $\mathcal{H}$ measurable. But I think we do not have this property, as we are only given $\pi_{F+G} (H) = \pi_G(H)$ which does not directly imply this.
Or does it?
My problem is, that $\pi_{F+G}$ can not be easily interpreted as a conditional expectation.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4936876/conditional-expectation-as-a-projection

Yes, I think I understand how $L^2$ projections relate to conditional expectation:
$E[X| \mathcal{F}]$ is the orthogonal projection of $X$ on to $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, which I write as $\pi_F$ above. Thus a conditional expectation like $E[X |\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}]$ would correspond to an orthogonal projection onto $L^2(\Omega, \sigma(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}), \mathbb{P})$, where $\sigma(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})$ is the "joint" of both sigma algebras. But this  subspace of $L^2$ is not $F+G$, which is what we are projecting on here.
Do I understand the problem correctly?

You are right: $E[1_B\mid\mathcal F,\mathcal G]$ is equal to $E[1_B\mid\mathcal G]$ plus a vector from the orthogonal space to $G$ that disappears when conditioned by $\mathcal G$.

Okay. I get that. We have $E[1_B | \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}] = E[1_B | \mathcal{G}] + Y$, where $Y \in G^\perp$. Clearly $E[Y | \mathcal{G}] = 0$. So in the derivation above we could use this to rewrite the fourth term in the equations as $E[ 1_A \cdot (E[1_B | \mathcal{G}] + Y) | \mathcal{G}]$ but we are still left with showing that $E[1_A \cdot Y | \mathcal{G}] = 0$.

It is enough to decompose $1_A$ as the sum of a vector of $G$ plus another orthogonal to it.

Sorry, I still don't quite get it. Could you elaborate on your solution? How do you use $\pi_{F+G}(H) = \pi_G(H)$?

I think I have misunderstood the statement of the theorem. I don't know if it means that the elements of $F$ and $H$ are independent or that the spaces $F$ and $H$, or their projections onto $G$, are orthogonal. I have looked for references in the book you mentioned but I cannot find the theorem you are referring to.

In my book it is Theorem 8.13 (conditional independence and orthogonality):
As part of the proof Kallenberg (the author) uses the equivalence I asked about (first equivalence of 4) and put as a "theorem" in my question. Unfortunately he does not go into much detail about how he arrived there. He also uses the $\lor$ both for the span of $F$ and $G$ (which I denoted as $F+G$) and also for the "joint" sigma algebra (like $\mathcal{F} \lor \mathcal{G} = \sigma(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})$. This notation makes it even harder for me precisely differentiate those (acutally quite different) notions.

I've looked at the theorem you're referring to:
$\mathcal{F}\underset{\mathcal{G}}{\bot\hspace{-5pt}\bot}\mathcal{H}\Rightarrow\pi_{F+G}(H)=\pi_{G}(H)$
seems correct, but
$\mathcal{F}\underset{\mathcal{G}}{\bot\hspace{-5pt}\bot}\mathcal{H}\Leftarrow\pi_{F+G}(H)=\pi_{G}(H)$
doesn't.

So I thought too - might be a mistake in the book. But I am convinced by now, that it does hold if we restrict our analysis to those $\sigma$-algebras that are generated by Borel-valued random variables. In this case we have the (interesting) property
$P(A | \sigma(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})) = E(E(1_A | \mathcal{F}) | \mathcal{G})$ for all $A \in \mathcal{H}$ (or any other combination of that kind), i.e. we can split up conditioning w.r.t. a joint of two $\sigma$-algebras into iterated conditioning. Using  this equality the reverse direction does hold (I hope).

I don't understand you, that (interesting) property is not true even in that case.
